# Multiple controller types were found that match the URL but different http verbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

We are getting this error,

```
Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.\r\n\r\nThe request has found the following matching controller types: 

NameSpace.AController
NameSpace.BController


[AllowAnonymous]
public class AController : Controller
{
    [Route("a1"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult A1()
    {
        return Content("A1");
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class BController : Controller
{
    [Route("a1"), HttpPost]
    public ActionResult A1()
    {
        return Content("B1");
    }
}
```

I have to allow different route names with http verb distinction.

Comment: Route constraint worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for this:

De URL matched because the route for the two methods matched. (base/A1 and base/A1.) Change you method A1 to B1. Then you have two different endpoints.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AController : Controller
{
    [Route("a1"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult A1()
    {
        return Content("A1");
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class BController : Controller
{
    [Route("b1"), HttpPost]
    public ActionResult B1()
    {
        return Content("B1");
    }
}
```

With this example your URL become: base/A1 and base/B1

It is also possible to set the controllername in the url:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AController : Controller
{
    [Route("a1"), HttpGet]
    public ActionResult A1()
    {
        return Content("A1");
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class BController : Controller
{
    [Route("A1"), HttpPost]
    public ActionResult A1()
    {
        return Content("B1");
    }
}
```

With this example your URL become: base/A/A1 and base/B/A1